# wso2 governance registry and scm with svn

Tags: svn, wso2

I am trying to setup up my governance repository to be backed by svn. This page seems simple enough but it is not working.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12421346

The mounted folder appears but no content in it. Am i missing a step here?

Here is my code in registry.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection checkOutURL="scm:svn:http://dev-code-repo/svn/wso2Dev/ESBConfig/synapse-configs" workingDir="/opt/wso2greg-4.5.0/repository/svn" mountPoint="/_system/foo" checkInURL="false" readOnly="true" updateFrequency="1">
            <username>tim</username>
            <password>password</password>
    </connection>
</scm
```

Comment: It might seem _too_ obvious, but since there's a lot of different levels of skill, let me ask the "dumb question".  You did create the svn repository you are attempting to connect to with the likes of `svnadmin create ...` and such?  If so, please update the question to explicitly state so.

Comment: i had assumed wso2 would be using a svn client in its library however it actually assumes the machine has svn installed on it and it uses that, which i didn't have at the time. In the end there are other bugs in registry 4.5.1/2/3 which prevent use of scm anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Not that I use a lot of wso2, but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the svnkit bundle to lib folder it still did not work. You need to install svn on the operating system as this is what it appears to use. To be honest this system is cause quite a few problems and i would recommend a different path if possible.